# Overwrite composer-installed dependencies

Tags: php, git, composer-php, asgardcms

I've recently inherited a project build on a particular PHP framework, Asgard. The framework itself is less important.

The code is stored on GitHub and contains the framework files, some of them modified, and a few dependencies. Upon installation, one should run `composer install`, which will bring the rest of the dependencies.

Most of the custom code is in two folders, located in `public_html/modules` and in `framework/Modules`, respectively. However, there are some framework files that have been modified.

The code management/installation procedure seems illogical to me, and I would rather all of the framework code (the specified version of it) would be brought by `composer` and only the few files be applied on top, as a patch.

Is there some development workflow that would allow me to push to GitHub just the changes, not all of the framework files, and then somehow apply a patch over the framework code when `composer install` runs?

I'm aware that composer is configured via `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, I just don't know how to do the patch.

Also, I don't know how to push just the changes to Git, without including the initial framework files, while retaining full functionality in my working folder.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should never modify dependencies code directly so maybe it'll be good to spend some time and fix that issue? If you want to override some methods you can just use inheritance and extend dependency classes.

Comment: Alternatively, you can fork the framework, push your changes to VCS, and use the patched version as a dependency in your composer.json